# Eloquent 3 tables relationship in Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuejs2

I have got this relationships:

```
 CUSTOMER
     id
     name

 ADDRESS
     id
     name
     customer_id
     country_id

 COUNTRY
     id
     name
```

My Customer model:

```
 class Customer extends Model
 {
     use SoftDeletes;

     public function addresses()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
     }
```

My address model:

```
    class Address extends Model
     {
         use SoftDeletes;

         public function country()
         {
             return $this->hasOne(Country::class);
         }
```

And right now doing:

```
  Customer::with('addresses')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
```

I can get all customer with his addresses. But How Can I get the name of country fro customer?

I know getting in blade, if I do 2 loops I can create $address variable and get country names:

```
  loop customers
     loop adddresses
        $address->name 
        $address->country (name of country)
```

But if I try in Vue:

```
   <tr v-for="(customer, index) in customers" :key="customer.id">
         <td>{{ customer.id}}</td>
         <td>{{ customer.firstname}}</td>
         <td>{{ customer.lastname}}</td>
         <td v-if="customer.addresses">
             <tr v-for="(address, index) in customer.addresses" :key="address.id">
                 <td>{{ address.name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ address.country }}</td>
             </tr>
         </td>
```

I dont get any value in addres.country. I mean, how Can I relate CUSTOMERS & COUNTRIES for usign in Vuejs?

Thans in advance

Comment: Did you try that `Customer::with(['addresses','addressess.country'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')` ?

Comment: Doesnt work. Relation country is in address Model because one customer can have more than one address. Also for this reason I need a loop  for addresses

Comment: I need  a way to get addresses data with his country name from Customers

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

I updated Address model like this:

```
 class Address extends Model
 {
     
     public function country()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
     }
    
     protected $with = ['country'];
 }
```

then I can solve country name like this:

```
 <tr v-for="(customer, index) in customers" :key="customer.id">
          <td>{{ customer.id}}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.name}}</td>
          <td v-if="customer.addresses">
              <tr v-for="(address, index) in customer.addresses" :key="address.id">
                  <td>{{ address.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ address.country.name }}</td>
              </tr>
          </td>
```